# Show Woocommerce minicart widget in checkout page sidebar? And, how to make this update secure by overriding widget?

Tags: widgets, templates, sidebar, plugins

Before asking question here I want to tell that I have already asked the question in stackoverflow and wordpress forum but have not got any answer. So finally I came here.

I have installed the [woocommerce plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/) in my [wordpress 3.5.2.](http://wordpress.org/) Everything is fine with woocommerce. I have made a folder called woocommerce and have pasted all the files inside the woocommerce template files inside my template folder. But there is something that I am totally stuck on. In the woocommerce checkout page I want to show cart totals in sidebar. But it is not showing there. In other pages it is working fine. So can someone kindly tell me what wrong here? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciated. Thanks

Update

Here is the screenshot for the woocommerce cart widget in sidebar which can be shown in all pages except the checkout page.

[image]

Edit:
Additional, how to make this change secure from updates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cart widget isn't showing because it's configured to not show on the `cart and checkout page`. If you want to change that take a look at `class-wc-widget-cart.php`, there you find the following line:

```
if ( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) return;
```

Change it to:

```
if ( is_cart() ) return;
```

To show the widget on the checkout page.

Note: This will be, if done in the plugins/woocommerce/classes/widgets folder, overwritten on updates.

---

Edit: Additional information how to override widget and make changes update secure
Source: http://www.skyverge.com/blog/overriddin-woocommerce-widgets/ (Option 5)

1. Duplicate `class-wc-widget-cart.php`;
2. Copy the duplicate into a folder inside your theme, for example: `cust_woo_widgets`
3. Make above changes to the file;
4. Additionally make the following change to the widget duplicate:

   ```
   class Custom_WooCommerce_Widget_Cart extends WooCommerce_Widget_Cart {
     function widget( $args, $instance ) {
   // copy the widget function from woocommerce/classes/widgets/class-wc-widget-cart.php
     }
   }
   ```
5. Put following code into your `functions.php`:

   ```
   add_action( 'widgets_init', 'override_woocommerce_widgets', 15 );
   function override_woocommerce_widgets() { 
     if ( class_exists( 'WooCommerce_Widget_Cart' ) ) {
       unregister_widget( 'WooCommerce_Widget_Cart' ); 
       include_once( 'cust_woo_widgets/widget-cart.php' );
       register_widget( 'Custom_WooCommerce_Widget_Cart' );
     } 
   }
   ```

Note: See source for more information; untested.

Comment: thanks for the reply but can you tell me what about the plugins update? Means when plugin will be updated then that will be override so how to solve this?

Comment: Generally you can override woocommerce templates: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/, but for widgets it isn't (allways) that easy to do. For more information how to do it, read this: http://www.skyverge.com/blog/overriddin-woocommerce-widgets/; and this: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/possible-to-overwrite-a-woocommerce-widget.

Answer (score 3):

I added the following code to my functions.php and now the cart is showing on all my pages.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_widget_cart_is_hidden', 'always_show_cart', 40, 0 );
function always_show_cart() {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: this should be the right solution, the filter got added by woocommerce - the answer from @something is outdated. 
you can also use the __return_false method:

add_filter( 'woocommerce_widget_cart_is_hidden', '__return_false', 40, 0 );

Comment: Both Filter dont work anymore - any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

It is not recommended to change the core file of the plugin as on the update your changes will be lost. Better use the following code to show cart widget in the sidebar on checkout page

```
add_filter('woocommerce_widget_cart_is_hidden', 'show_cart_on_checkout');

    function show_cart_on_checkout()
    {
        return is_cart();
    }
```